# Making pogo strike work?

Tags: flinthook

How does the pogo strike attack work in Flintstrike? The way the card reads you should jump over an enemy and hold down the fastfall into an enemy and you damage them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are fast falling pogostrike isn't already active. When fast falling with this perk equipped you will hear a sound effect and there will be a visual indicator on the screen of anything that is below you to be damaged.